# I need help for a specific sql query

Tags: sql

I have the following sql query:

```
select Judge, ResultIndex, count(*) as CasesForJudge
from SRSIndexes
group by Judge, ResultIndex
```

The columns `"Judge"` and `"ResultIndex"` are `nvarchar` type. I recieve output like this:

```
Adelina Andreeva  2a           24
Adelina Andreeva  5b           33
....
Georgy Ivanov     3b           44
Georgy Ivanov     5a           5
```

I want to find the sums (from `"CasesForJudge"` column) for each judge (for example: `Adelina Andreeva -> 57`, `Georgy Ivanov -> 49`). How should i modify my query?

Comment: What's your RDBMS, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `GROUP BY` your `Judge` column

```
SELECT Judge, count(*) AS CasesForJudge
FROM SRSIndexes
GROUP BY Judge
```

Comment: Edit: Cleaned up the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want *both* groupings in *one query* you can try `grouping sets`:

```
    select Judge, 
           ResultIndex, 
           count(*) as CasesForJudge
      from SRSIndexes
  group by grouping sets ((Judge, ResultIndex), -- Initial grouping 
                          (Judge))              -- Added one
```